# Can I dynamically control concurrency of a map function in Spark?

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-spark

I am applying a `map` function that does some ETL over my data. This function is usually very quick and ,as data are well distributed, there are enough tasks created so I get a nice and uniform utilization.

The problem is that the `map` function will, on certain data combinations, become I/O bound. What happens is that typically the triggering data will appear on a single block (they arrive in sequence) and hence be picked up by a single node/task. What happens then is that processing of 100GBs takes 5-6 seconds and processing of that single block (256mb in MapR) takes 20 minutes as it is being executed by a single thread.

Is there a way to increase parallelization just for this block? 
What would someone typically do in this situation?

The options I have identified so far (which I would describe as workarounds) are:

1. `spark.default.parallelism` : This will affect the global execution and result in sub-optimal overall times. Although the docs state that this is the parallelism of shuffle operations, I have observed that it also affects `map` parallelism. Can you please elaborate on what happens internally? Does this override the way blocks are processed?
2. `spark.task.cpus` : This is too coarse-grained and again it will affect the global execution characteristics.
3. Use `fork/join` inside the `map` function and delegate to an `ExecutorService` when I/O bound delays are detected: This complicates things and takes resources control from the framework that will materialize in bad situation that are hard to resolve.
4. `sc.textFile("theFile.txt", 100)` : This will affect my main RDD (which is 100GB) and subsequent transformations/actions for the whole set. A bit better tahn 1, but still not ideal (Updated from pzecevic's answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the parallelism on the RDD on which you are apply the map transformation.

```
rdd.repartition(100)
```

I don't know how you are creating the RDD, but sometimes you can specify parallelism on RDD creation:

```
sc.textFile("theFile.txt", 100)
```

This will directly influence the number of mapping tasks (100 in this case).

Comment: upvoted mainly for the `rdd.repartition(100)`. Was aware of the `sc.textFile(...,100)` but forgot to mention it. The latter is more fined grained that my other options, but still suffers because this 256mb block is part of my main rdd(100GBs). If I don't get a better answer, I'll mark as such, as I might be able to use a filter to flush them out and then repartition

Comment: @IoannisDeligiannis - You should use something like `rdd = rdd.repartition(sc.defaultParallelism * 3)` to dynamically repartition according to the number of cores in your cluster. This will give you 3 tasks per core, which is [recommended in general by the Spark Tuning Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/tuning.html#level-of-parallelism).